# DISM /Capture-FFU and /Apply-FFU is painfully slow

Tags: windows, disk-image, deployment, dism, winpe

I need to capture+apply an entire disk image with [Windows Full Flash Update (FFU)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-windows-using-full-flash-update--ffu)
It seems an [interesting improvement compared to WIM images](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats), also they state that it is faster... but it doesn't seem so to me.
My system is composed by:

- Boot partition (less than 500 MB)
- Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 2016 partition (60 GB, 50% used)
- Another primary partition (40 GB, 30% used)

Also, the hardware is pretty good! Intel i7-7700H, 32 GB RAM, 128 GB SSD.

I boot with a WinPE (latest ADK version - Windows 10, 1809) USB and run this:

`powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=g:\test.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0`

It took **2 hours to complete** and generate a 30 GB FFU file.
The version of DISM is 10.0.17763.1

Same thing for the apply phase:

`powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
DISM.exe /apply-ffu /imagefile=g:\test.ffu /applydrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive0`

It seems slow to be because in [this article](https://win10.guru/windows-ffu-image-faster-capture-deployment/) the author says "*FFU takes about 15 minutes to create a 28 GB FFU image*".

Comment: I assume you are taking an image of a physical machine instead of a virtual machine? I assume the time difference is the second partition you are creating image of (and the fact you likely have 50% more data) then the author did).

Comment: Yes it is a physical machine. You say that the second partition may slow down everything? It seems way too much slowdown to me...

Comment: @Ramhound yes, my data is 50% more... but the hardware is faster so I expected, more or less, 15x2 minutes... 2 hours is an huge difference instead.

Comment: Your hardware isn't that much faster, and the major bottlekneck in this case, would be the storage device.  Your faster processor wouldn't have that much of an impact on I/O reads and writes.